# How to make each tableview cell present different detail view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new to swift but I learned a lot for the past two months.
I am building an app where you have a list of products in table view and when a cell is pressed it presents you to a new view controller where a page view shows the product's categories.
I managed to make everything except when I click on a different cell it presents the same page view controller.
So my question is how to make each cell presents a  different page view controller with different details about the product?

Here is my didSellectRowAtIndexPath code :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)
{

    var detailedViewController: ViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as ViewController


    self.presentViewController(detailedViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I can provide more information about the code just tell me what should be of your help to understand my idea.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can apply if else if condition to check which row is clicked in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and present view accordingly. check indexPath.row..!

Comment: Either add a public datasource-related property to set at the instance `detailedViewController` of the same type or make it so that `detailedViewController ` is initialised depending on the `indexPath` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question it seems you *want* to present the *same* page view controller, only with different details.

Create a segue in storyboard to the detail controller and configure it in `prepareForSegue`. Assuming you have a data array `productsArray` with your products as the datasource:

```
let detailController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailController
let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell // or your cell subclass
let point = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView:tableView)
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)
detailController.product = productArray[indexPath.row]!
```

Obviously, your detail controller will have a `product` property and will configure its UI with the details from this object.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant, thank you very much